# Dygraph - Option 'follow' for legend is not working

Tags: dygraphs

I have a simple js function:

```
function render_dygraph(container, data, labelnames){
  var options = {
     labels: labelnames,
     legend: 'follow'
    }
  new Dygraph(container, data, options);
}
```

The legend is still in the default location and not following the pointer. If I change it to 'always', it does work. I haven't done any css changes or any other changes anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: which version of dygraphs are you using? `legend: follow` was [added](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2014/12/dygraphs-110.html) in the 1.1 release.

Comment: I switched to version 1.1 and it started working. However, I am showing multiple series in the graph, and the legend is displayed at the location of the bottom-most point. I would prefer it located centrally or at the exact pointer location.

Answer (score 0):

Check to use "href" and not "src" for stylesheet, causing 'follow' not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/dygraphs/dist/dygraph.css">
```